# Plotting two histograms over each other - why are they plotting on the same X column?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two lists of floats. I can see that the floats in the two lists range from 0.003 to 0.99.

The lists are too long to paste here, but they would look like this:

```
list1 = [0.03, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.993]
list2 = [0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.7, 0.002, 0.4, 0.01, 0.3]
```

and I can see that there is definitely values in the list ranging from <0.1 to >0.9.

When I run this code to plot both of these lists as histograms on one plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(list1, alpha=0.5)
plt.hist(list2,alpha=0.5)
plt.savefig('test_histogram.png')
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

But there's no error. There's definitely plenty of values <0.8 so it's not just that the values are so small that they're not seen. Would someone have an explanation of what's happening?

Comment: What's your `matplotlib.__version__`? I get very different output when I plot your code in 3.5.1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4l4OQ.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass 'histtype' as bar

```
plt.hist(list1, alpha=0.5, density=True, histtype='bar')

plt.hist(list2,alpha=0.5, density=True, histtype='bar')

plt.show()`
```

output:
[image: outpot]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).